# TailwindCSS's output file is empty after using the build command

Tags: css, npm, tailwind-css

I tried using TailwindCSS on MacOS. I installed it with the following command:

`npm install -D tailwindcss`

Then to create the configuration file, I ran the following command:

`npx tailwindcss init`

Then I configured my configuration file (tailwind.config.js) to the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

After adding a few files my explorer looks like this:

[image]

Finally, I ran the following command expecting some CSS to appear in my `output.css` file:

`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

I checked my `output.css` file and it was empty. By the way, in my `input.css` file I entered the following lines of code:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

However after running the previous command saw see the following messages in my terminal:

```
warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: what module bundler tool your using? or any framework?

Comment: I don't know if I'm even using a module bundler. If Node.js counts, then I'm using that.

Comment: module bundler are webpack, vite, parcel,... You can use them to make static site

Comment: I do not recall using any of them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are exporting the output CSS into `./src`.
Try to change the `tailwind.config.js` into the code below:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./dist/**/*.{html,css ,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you click on debug as shown in image and than click on build it will make your style.css written

see this image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPXIk.png

Comment: Avoid sharing answers as an image - provide your answer directly as code in the post